# How to create rounded corners on a thumbnail using php and html?

Tags: php, html

func.php file where it generates a thumbnail when an image is uploaded to website.  I understand how to make the corners rounded by radius of 5 but for some reason I am stumped right now where to incorporate the round corners into my code, please help:

```
<?php
function create_thumb($directory, $image, $destination) {
  $image_file = $image;
  $image = $directory.$image;

if (file_exists($image)) {

$source_size = getimagesize($image);

if ($source_size !== false) {

  $thumb_width = 100;
  $thumb_height = 100;

  switch($source_size['mime']) {
    case 'image/jpeg':
         $source = imagecreatefromjpeg($image);
    break;
    case 'image/png':
         $source = imagecreatefrompng($image);
    break;
    case 'image/gif':
         $source = imagecreatefromgif($image);
    break;
  }

  $source_aspect = round(($source_size[0] / $source_size[1]), 1);
  $thumb_aspect = round(($thumb_width / $thumb_height), 1);

  if ($source_aspect < $thumb_aspect) {
    $new_size = array($thumb_width, ($thumb_width / $source_size[0]) * $source_size[1]);
    $source_pos = array(0, ($new_size[1] - $thumb_height) / 2);
  } else if ($source_aspect > $thumb_aspect) {
    $new_size = array(($thumb_width / $source_size[1]) * $source_size[0], $thumb_height);
    $source_pos = array(($new_size[0] - $thumb_width) / 2, 0);
  } else {
    $new_size = array($thumb_width, $thumb_height);
    $source_pos = array(0, 0);
  }

  if ($new_size[0] < 1) $new_size[0] = 1;
  if ($new_size[1] < 1) $new_size[1] = 1;

  $thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($thumb_width, $thumb_height);
  imagecopyresampled($thumb, $source, 0, 0, $source_pos[0], $source_pos[1], $new_size[0], $new_size[1], $source_size[0], $source_size[1]);

  switch($source_size['mime']) {
    case 'image/jpeg':
         imagejpeg($thumb, $destination.$image_file);
    break;
    case 'image/png':
          imagepng($thumb, $destination.$image_file);
    break;
    case 'image/gif':
         imagegif($thumb, $destination.$image_file);
    break;
  }


}

  }
}
?>
```

Comment: Couldn't you just use CSS's `border-radius`? If you use http://css3pie.com/ it will work even on IE6 :)

Comment: Yes CSS is better and elegant solution. Why don't you use it?

Comment: possible duplicate of this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/609109/rounded-corners-on-images-using-php?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code looks like its part of the image making process
To style the image, you need to be working on the output of that file
Do you have code that generates `HTML` for the client side?
If so, then give each `img` a class and use `CSS` to give it the corners

```
.ui-corner-all { -moz-border-radius: 4px; -webkit-border-radius: 4px; border-radius: 4px; }
```

Comment: yes I see it now I was way over thinking it for some reason, your right that's why I could not figure out how to incorporate that into that file because it's not practical.  Thank you.